# Memory limitations on interfacing SD Card with 4-bit SD data transfer mode

Tags: memory, sd

I am trying to interface a 4GB SD Card in my application using 4-bit SD data transfer mode, but some of my friends said that the 4-bit SD data transfer mode supports upto 2GB SD Cards and above that memory you should use SPI interface. Is it true that the use of 4-bit SD data transfer mode only works upto 2GB. If yes, why is it like that?

Comment: refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Storage_capacity_and_incompatibilities). It mainly depends on the format being used. 4 GB can be interfaced.But, supporting all SD cards will definitely have limitation. What kind of SD card is being interfaced?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's nonsense. SD and SPI modes can both be used to access data on any size of card.

What is true is that SDHC cards (that is, SD cards larger than 2 GB) must be initialized differently than plain SD cards (2 GB or less). However, this is true no matter whether you're using the SD interface or SPI.